# LCD Zebra display, repair bonding (ITO Trace?)

Tags: lcd, repair, trace

Is there a way to repair the "traces" displayed below?

I don't have any idea about the subject, but maybe painting them with a conductive paint? I could create a template with the traces, and then drag paint over them

Thank you

[image: LCD traces]

Comment: Successful repair is extremely unlikely. What makes you think there's a problem with the traces on the glass?

Comment: If the ITO traces are damaged, nothing short of [sputtering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sputtering) new ones will help.

Comment: I have tried several times to use this screen and it fails whatsoever. I have another one that works and this one doesn't, even changing zebra stripes.

Comment: You may try to make a stencil similar to SMT solder paste one and cover the pads with electroconductive spray.

Comment: @MichalPodmanický After removing a flex I see the slight reflection of some trace on the glass of the LCD (very hard to see, they show only on some angle, the same of this video). They look perfect, but they are conductive (no continuity). Aren't they supposed to be conductive? If not how that work? I see on youtube someone else with the same trace sticking a flex on it, but once again, how that work? YT: https://youtu.be/yrgkRAXzCpo?t=27